# Improve this query

Tags: sql, postgresql

do you know if there is a way to improve this query?

The database where this query runs is very large, and it could take a lot of time to return the result.

We have indexes on field_1, field_2 and state

We are using Postgres

```sql
SELECT id
FROM a
WHERE 
(field_1 = 999 OR field_2 = 876) AND state IN ('finished', 'closed')
ORDER BY created_at desc
```

One suggestion that I get is to split this query in two and then remove the "OR".

Another suggestion is to add some "pagination"

Comment: should pagination it i would say. It's always going to take a while if you want to get millions of rows. Paging should allow quick less expensive queries.

Comment: Don't split it. How many rows do you expect to retrieve from the query?

Comment: Hi @JonathanJacobson its a hard million rows database, I spect a lot of thousands of Ids, it depended on the params really.
for example field_1 is the id for a person. This person could have thousand of task with the required states in the IN() statement. The hay cumulative for each person through time

Comment: If you're sure that you need all IDs (sounds unlikey) and you must have the data sorted, then please run this query with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE TRUE, BUFFERS TRUE) SELECT ...` and post the execution details in the question.

Comment: Also: `SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_stats WHERE tablename = 'a' AND attname IN ('id','field_1','field_2','state','created_at');`

Comment: Pagination could only be faster if you don't fetch all the pages.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be quite hard to optimize as written.  If you phrase this as:

```
SELECT id
FROM ((SELECT a.*
       FROM a
       WHERE field_1 = 999 AND state IN ('finished', 'closed')
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT a.*
       FROM a
       WHERE field_2 = 876 AND state IN ('finished', 'closed') and field_1 <> 999
      )
     ) a
ORDER BY created_at desc;
```

Then Postgres can use different indexes for each subquery:

- `(field_1, state)`
- `(field_2, state, field_1)`

Comment: No need to split like that. PostgreSQL knows very well how to scan multiple indexes and perform bitmap operations, when applicable.